# Python elasticsearch-dsl sorting with multiple fields

Tags: python, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to form the command for sorting using elasticsearch-dsl. However I have trouble passing the variable in correct format in.

The format should be

```
s=Search()
s = s.sort({"time":{"order":"asc"}}, {"anoter_field":{"order":"desc"}})
s.execute()
```

The problem is I'm trying to put `{"time":{"order":"asc"}}, {"anoter_field":{"order":"desc"}}` as a variable, but I can't seem to get this in the right syntax. I tried using dict, list, and string, and none seems to work.

My input would be a dict that looks like

```
input = {"time":"asc", "another_field":"desc"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
data_input = {"time":"asc", "another_field":"desc"}
args = [{k:{'order':v}} for k,v in data_input.items()]
s.sort(*args)
```

I guess is what you are asking? Its hard to tell ...

Comment: yes.... you got it exactly right. Is it the `*` that makes passing in a list okay?

Comment: yep thats called list unpacking

Comment: Your answer completely satisfies my need but, I'm filtering using `{"name": "asc", "age": "asc"}` in this case my result is just taking age as the only parameter to sort, ignoring sorting by name.